# Управление зуммером компьютера через Python

Tags: python, bat

Есть ли возможность управления зуммером компьютера через код на Python?
Если нет возможности делать это напрямую через Python, то можно ли реализовать это через bat-файл, а уже его запускать через Python?

Comment: Чем звуковой файл не угодил?

Comment: Нужен вывод не через динамики компьютера, а через зуммер, который пищит при каждом запуске компьютера

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise